# insert same values to table with unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert same values into a table with a unique column. I don't want to run a  long insert script on database.

For instance;

```
INSERT INTO a (x,y,z) VALUES ('0001','w','SG')
INSERT INTO a (x,y,z) VALUES ('0002','w','SG')
INSERT INTO a (x,y,z) VALUES ('0002','w','SG')
.
.
.

INSERT INTO a (x,y,z) VALUES ('1000','w','SG')
```

I am looking for a simple solution.

Comment: make column 'x' to be self increment (identity (1,1))

Comment: Same values when unique? Easiest way - to do what?

Answer (score 1):

To me looks like you are looking for `IDENTITY` in `SQL SERVER`. You can consider marking your column `x` as identity column saying `x IDENTITY (1,1)` in which case your `x` column value will increase (by default, it will increment by seed value 1) on every insertion of new record.

Comment: I can not change table structure, is there a possible modification for insert clause.

Comment: @Mustafa, am afraid but No there isn't any

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must right click on your table and select "Design"

In the pane on the bottom you must set Identity Specification to "Yes" as below

[image: Id Spec]

With this every time you insert a new record the ID field will be automatically incremented, without the need to insert it yourself.